# How to update script c#

Tags: c#

Okay so I understand the basics of c# and have been using unity3d previously to  trying out Visual Studios.

At the moments I have a simple button and a Textbox with the script below. I have it so that when the button is pressed it would change the Text in the textbox. (I know this is simple, im getting used to Visual Studios). What I was expecting to happen was for the text to change on that frame however it only changes once I try to type something in the textbox. Is there something like Update() in unity that updates everything inside every frame or how would I go about getting a similar result? Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplicationTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool ButtonIsPressed = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonIsPressed == true)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "ButtonIsPressed is true!";
        } else if (ButtonIsPressed == false)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "ButtonIsPressed is false!";
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonIsPressed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not update this.textBox1.Text in button1_Click?

Comment: Changing the text inside of the TextChanged event seems like a bad idea...

Comment: @David it's ok for demonstration purposes I guess

Comment: @8673589, are you expecting textBox1_TextChange to run whenever you WANT the text to be changed?  I think your concept of events might be wrong.  There isn't a rendering loop like you have in games.

Comment: Ah yes Jerry that makes sense. I can see how that would work. derp

Comment: Unity works with an Update() method, where you say, what to do on rerenders e.g. The Engine itself triggers Update() automatically, so the misunderstood of programming in C# ;) I had the similar problem the other way round ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrey said, `TextChanged` triggers only, if the Text in the field is changed. To get the result you want, you have to use other events:

```
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "pressed";
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "not pressed";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way winforms work (unlike unity) is with events, you have an event handler for each control and when he is triggered the method registered on it will occur.
In your case you have a textbox with an event handler that textBox1_TextChanged was registered to it and when you have any changes in the text box the method - textBox1_TextChanged  will be invoked. If you want multiple actions to happen when the textbox will change just register all of them (the functions) to the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that happens on a button click is that the value of your `ButtonIsPressed` variable changes. And typing something in your textbox triggers the `TextChanged` event that is handled by your `textBox1_TextChanged` method. And the content of the textbox is then modified inside that handler.